# Autwire is Kafka Configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am not able to autowire MyRestcall in the MySerialiser class.

Its throwing NPE as MyRestcall isnt getting autowired.How cani autowire it.

MyRestcall is annoted with @Service annotation.

```
@Configuration
public class KakfaConfiguration {



@Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, MyMessage> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        
        

        config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, MySerializer.class);

}


import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;

public class MySerializer implements Serializer {
    
    

    @Autowired
    private MyRestcall myRestcall;
    
    
    
    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, Object data) {
        
            myRestcall.m1();
    
            return out.toByteArray();
        } catch (Exception e) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, MySerializer.class);
```

With this configuration, Kafka creates the serializer, not Spring.

You need to define `MySerializer` as a `@Bean` and pass it into the producer factory directly.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean; it's best to ask a new question with more details.

Comment: +1 to Gary's answer. I really missed the fact that you try to inject into non-managed instance. The `MySerializer.class` is not going to be a bean with that config.

Comment: @GaryRussell i added the below code in my configuration class `@Bean
 public MySerializer mySerializer()
 {
  return new MySerializer();
 }`
and `  config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,mySerializer());`
But i got the error
`org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value for configuration value.serializer: Expected a Class instance or class name.
`What i am doing wrong

Comment: You need to add the bean to the `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` using the `Constructor` or `setValueSerializer()` instead of via the property.